# Binary tree - find position in inorder traversal

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, inorder

I have a binary search tree where i have to implement a method called

```
int valueAtPosition(int x)
```

The problem is, that i need the position in an in order traversal.

To find the in order traversal i have this the following code, but i don't know how i count the recursive calls, to get the right position.

```
public void inOrderTraverseTree(Node root){
    if(root != null){
        inOrderTraverseTree(root.leftChild);
        System.out.println(root);
        inOrderTraverseTree(root.rightChild); 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a counter in the recursive approach. However, you can't simply pass an `int counter` argument - you need all calls to see the "same" counter, so you will have to wrap it in a class (or, as in this case, an inner class):

```
public static class Counter {
   private int value;
   public Counter(int initialValue) { value = initialValue; }
   public boolean decrement() { value--; return value == 0; }
   public boolean expired() { return value <= 0; }
}

public Node inOrderTraverseTree(Node root, Counter counter){
   if  (root != null && ! counter.expired()) {
       Node left = inOrderTraverseTree(root.leftChild, counter);
       if (left != null) {
            return left;
       } else if (counter.decrement()) {
            return root;
       } else {
            return inOrderTraverseTree(root.rightChild, counter); 
       }
   } else {
       return null;
   }
}
```

To find the 9th node in-order (using 1-based indexing), you would call this as

```
Node the9th = inOrderTraverseTree(root, new Counter(9));
```

If there *is* no 9th node, it would return `null`. If you want to use 0-based indexing instead, change `{ value--; return value == 0; }` to `{ return value-- == 0; }`

Answer (score 4):

I think the other solutions are O(n). All you need for this is a count of the children for each node for O(log n).

When you insert a node, for each node you traverse you increase the counter on the traversed node by one.

You need to maintain these counters when deleting, rebalancing, etc which normally isn't difficult.

With this you can get the position of the node when inserted, find the position of a node by value or find a node by position.

To find a node by position is the same kind of binary traversal as for finding by value. If you want the item at position 1000 then you start at the root. No root, not item at that position. Then you look at the left child (you can do it in the other order too and switch ascending/descending), on the left if the left child exists the number of children on the left is 0 plus the count of the children on the left node. Let say in this scenario that the left exists and has 500 children. Then you know 1000 can't be left because there aren't enough items on the left, so it must be right. You can repeat this also checking for bounds all the way down.

For simple O(n) in order traversal if you have a global counter you just increase it only after traversing the left. That should do the same as a depth first search. No need for decreasing and increasing counters or pushing and popping on a stack. You can also have your functions return a count.

```
public int inOrderTraverseTree(Node root){
    if(root == null)
        return 0;

    int count = inOrderTraverseTree(root.leftChild);
    count++;
    count += inOrderTraverseTree(root.rightChild);
    return count;
}
```

This approach only becomes annoying if you want to return the node as well.

You can of course replace a recursive function with your own stack but this is a rarely needed performance optimisation and you'll be far better off with the O(log n) solution if you need performance than an optimised custom stack based solution.

Answer (score 1):

The iterative in-order traversal approach makes this pretty easy. Increment a counter whenever a node is popped from the stack. When the counter is equal to x, return the value of the node.

```
Integer valueAtPosition(int x, Node root) {
  int count = 0;
  List<Node> stack = new ArrayList<>();
  Node node = root;
  while (!stack.isEmpty() || node != null) {
    if (node != null) {
      stack.add(node);
      node = node.leftChild;
    } else {
      node = stack.pop();
      if (count == x) {
        return node.value;
      }
      count++;
      node = node.rightChild;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Recursive version requires passing a mutable wrapper for a counter like so:

```
public class Counter {
   int count = 0;
}

public void inOrderTraverseTree(Node root, int index, Counter counter){
  if(root == null || counter.count > index) {
    return;
  }
  inOrderTraverseTree(root.leftChild);
  if (counter.count == index) {
    System.out.println(root);
  }
  counter.count = counter.count + 1;
  inOrderTraverseTree(root.rightChild); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is recursive in-order traversal approach: (in c++)

```
bool valueAtPositionUtil(struct treeNode *root, int &currIndex, int i, int &value) {
    if(root != NULL) {
        if(valueAtPositionUtil(root->left, currIndex, i, value)) {
            return true;
        }
        if(currIndex == i) {
            value = root->data;
            return true;
        }
        currIndex++;
        if(valueAtPositionUtil(root->right, currIndex, i, value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int ValueAtPosition(int i, struct treeNode *root) {
    int value = 0;
    int currIndex = 0;
    if(valueAtPositionUtil(root, currIndex, i, value)) {
        return value;
    }
    //index out of bound
    // you can return according your problem
    return -1; 
}
```