# Finding the rank of a student GPA in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I've read all the posts related to this question, yet I am still having a very hard time understanding how to implement the algorithm.

I have a fully written BST with methods that recursively add, delete etc `Student` objects(the BST class is written for generics, though). I need to write a method that returns the rank of a student in the binary search tree based off their GPA, yet I do not understand how I should implement this. The `Student` class has a getGPA() method, so I know ill need to use that somehow.

Should I store the elements into an array then search for the index? If so, what's the best algorithm to accomplish this? Is there a better way to do this?

Here is the important parts of my BST class:

```
public int size()
    // Returns the number of elements in this BST.
    {
      return recSize(root);
    }
private int recSize(BSTNode<T> tree)
  // Returns the number of elements in tree.
  {
    if (tree == null)    
      return 0;
    else
      return recSize(tree.getLeft()) + recSize(tree.getRight()) + 1;
  }
private boolean recContains(T element, BSTNode<T> tree)
  // Returns true if tree contains an element e such that 
  // e.compareTo(element) == 0; otherwise, returns false.
  {
    if (tree == null)
      return false;       // element is not found
    else if (element.compareTo(tree.getInfo()) < 0)
      return recContains(element, tree.getLeft());   // Search left subtree
    else if (element.compareTo(tree.getInfo()) > 0)
      return recContains(element, tree.getRight());  // Search right subtree
    else
      return true;        // element is found
  }

  public boolean contains (T element)
  // Returns true if this BST contains an element e such that 
  // e.compareTo(element) == 0; otherwise, returns false.
  {
    return recContains(element, root);
  }
private T recGet(T element, BSTNode<T> tree)
  // Returns an element e from tree such that e.compareTo(element) == 0;
  // if no such element exists, returns null.
  {
    if (tree == null)
      return null;             // element is not found
    else if (element.compareTo(tree.getInfo()) < 0)
      return recGet(element, tree.getLeft());          // get from left subtree
    else
    if (element.compareTo(tree.getInfo()) > 0)
      return recGet(element, tree.getRight());         // get from right subtree
    else
      return tree.getInfo();  // element is found
  }

  public T get(T element)
  // Returns an element e from this BST such that e.compareTo(element) == 0;
  // if no such element exists, returns null.
  {
    return recGet(element, root);
  }

  private BSTNode<T> recAdd(T element, BSTNode<T> tree)
  // Adds element to tree; tree retains its BST property.
  {
    if (tree == null)
      // Addition place found
      tree = new BSTNode<T>(element);
    else if (element.compareTo(tree.getInfo()) <= 0)
      tree.setLeft(recAdd(element, tree.getLeft()));    // Add in left subtree
    else
      tree.setRight(recAdd(element, tree.getRight()));   // Add in right subtree
    return tree;
  }

  public void add (T element)
  // Adds element to this BST. The tree retains its BST property.
  {
    root = recAdd(element, root);
  }
private void inOrder(BSTNode<T> tree)
  // Initializes inOrderQueue with tree elements in inOrder order.
  {
    if (tree != null)
    {
      inOrder(tree.getLeft());
      inOrderQueue.enqueue(tree.getInfo());
      inOrder(tree.getRight());
    }
  }
private void preOrder(BSTNode<T> tree)
  // Initializes preOrderQueue with tree elements in preOrder order.
  {
    if (tree != null)
    {
      preOrderQueue.enqueue(tree.getInfo());
      preOrder(tree.getLeft());
      preOrder(tree.getRight());
    }
  }

  private void postOrder(BSTNode<T> tree)
  // Initializes postOrderQueue with tree elements in postOrder order.
  {
    if (tree != null)
    {
      postOrder(tree.getLeft());
      postOrder(tree.getRight());
      postOrderQueue.enqueue(tree.getInfo());
    }
  }

  public int reset(int orderType)
  // Initializes current position for an iteration through this BST
  // in orderType order. Returns current number of nodes in the BST.
  {
    int numNodes = size();

    if (orderType == INORDER)
    {
      inOrderQueue = new LinkedUnbndQueue<T>();
      inOrder(root);
    }
    else
    if (orderType == PREORDER)
    {
      preOrderQueue = new LinkedUnbndQueue<T>();
      preOrder(root);
    }
    if (orderType == POSTORDER)
    {
      postOrderQueue = new LinkedUnbndQueue<T>();
      postOrder(root);
    }
    return numNodes;
  }
```

Comment: Are you just trying to find the GPA by finding a student inside of the tree and getting is GPA value? If so, there are many tree traversal methods that can help greatly in trying to iterate through a tree recursively in order to find a specific node or a specific object at a node. Here is a url:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order_2

Comment: You seem to have a method, `inOrdrer`, which adds the objects to an ordered queue. Just do that and then find the index of your object in the queue.

Comment: @Raheel138 OP is not trying to find the GPA. OP is trying to find someone's class rank given their GPA.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013591/binary-tree-find-position-in-inorder-traversal

Answer (score 0):

After several failures, it seems I have found a workable solution. Instead of storing in a generic array with a fixed size, I decided to try an ArrayList instead. I use a recursive method to add each node inorder to the array list:

```
//recursive method used to copy BST to array list
    public void recArrayList(BSTNode<T> tree, ArrayList<T> list)
    {
        if (tree == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        recArrayList(tree.getLeft(), list);
        list.add(tree.getInfo());
        recArrayList(tree.getRight(), list);
    }

    //converts BST to arraylist used for finding GPA rank
    public ArrayList<T> toArrayList()
    {
        stuList = new ArrayList<T>();
        recArrayList(root, stuList);
        return stuList;
    }
```

And finally in the class using the BST:

```
//returns the rank of student in BST based off GPA
    public int rank(Student stu)
    {
        ArrayList<Student> stuList = stuGPA.toArrayList();
        for (i = 0; i < stuList.size(); i++)
        {
            if (stuList.get(i) == stu)
            {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I dont like using `==` to compare references so i'm working on changing that, but for now this seems to be functioning correctly. Ty for the comments, it inspired me to go a different route.